# Should I update UI elements from OnPostExecute of AsyncTask or not?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, ui-thread

In my android application, I want to strictly follow the Android guidelines. So after executing the `AsyncTask`, I have 2 options to update the UI with the results.

1. I can either send the results back the main thread using a call-back listener and update the UI from there.
2. I can also pass a reference of the desired UI elements to `AsyncTask` and update these elements in `onPostExecute`.

So, which approach is better and why?

Comment: Your both approach will be correct. Try any as per your convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to actually understand Threading, if it is a simple **call-back listener**, it won't change the thread in which the code is running. If this is the case, then methods (1) and (2) would be more or less the same.

If you are actually referring to using a `Handler`, then it has some differences, a `Handler` actually queue up the callback and call it later in the Thread in which the `Handler` is created.

However, as `OnPostExecute` is already in `UI Thread`, it means it is ok to update UI element as (2). And the **most important** point you should be aware is that your `Activity` could be destroyed at the time `OnPostExecute` is called. If so, you should not modify the UI with the `Activity` reference which the `AsyncTask` is created with.

Answer (score 0):

Background tasks that are long are run on `onBackground` function of `AsyncTask`. At the end of `onBackground`, `onPostExecute` is called where you should do UI changes.

It works fine if you have your `AsyncTask` inside your Activity. You can just update UI views inside `onPostExecute` since you have access to them.

When your `AsyncTask` is a separate class and you don't have access to UI views of your Activity then inside your `onPostExecute` function you can return results to your `Activity` and update UI there.

Comment: How to return results to your activity  by onPostExecute() when Async is declared in another file ??

Comment: Easiest way is to use an event bus. Try looking at Otto, it's only couple of lines of code http://square.github.io/otto/

Answer (score 0):

Both cases work well if you want to update your ui after a task finishes. `onPostExecute` also processes code in the main thread. Which approach is better? It depends on how you want to organize your code structure.

1. If you just want to update your UI. I think it's better to update them inside `onPostExecute`, because your code would be more simple and clear.
2. However, using a callback is more flexible. Since you can do what ever you want with the task result according to your passing callback.